Find product ID in shipment
I want to find which ProductID belongs to which ShippingID. I have the ProductMade time, so I need to find between which ShippingTime the ProductMade fits in order to find the ShippingID.
I'm using MS Access as data source.
Product



ProductID
ProductMade




11205
2024-05-29 17:27


11921
2024-05-29 17:12


12324
2024-05-29 16:53


12328
2024-05-29 16:37


11851
2024-05-29 15:54


12354
2024-05-29 14:13


12333
2024-05-29 13:51


12342
2024-05-29 13:36


20014
2024-05-29 13:16


11822
2024-05-29 12:52



Shipping



ShippingTime
ShippingID




2024-05-29 12:49
I0230


2024-05-28 19:31
J0130


2024-05-29 05:04
J0140


2024-05-29 13:37
J0340


2024-05-29 17:05
J0410


2024-05-28 17:07
J0430


2024-05-29 11:24
K0120


2024-05-29 07:01
K0310


2024-05-28 15:01
K0510


2024-05-28 23:43
K0830


2024-05-29 01:48
K0940


2024-05-29 10:12
K1020


2024-05-29 15:57
K1030


2024-05-28 22:02
K1220


2024-05-29 03:41
K1240


2024-05-29 15:51
K1340



I have tried different SQL statements, but I never get the result I want. I don't know how to use BETWEEN properly so that one value (time) is at the head of the query.

BETWEEN probably won't be useful because there are not two fields in Shipping for ProductMade to be between. Need Shipping ID that has ShippingTime closest to and >=ProductMade. This involves a correlated subquery. Be aware this can perform slowly with large dataset.
SELECT Product.ProductID, Product.ProductMade, (
    SELECT TOP 1 ShippingID FROM Shipping 
    WHERE Shipping.ShippingTime >= Product.ProductMade
    ORDER BY ShippingTime) AS ShipID
FROM Product;




ProductID
ProductMade
ShipID




11205
5/29/2024 5:27:00 PM



11921
5/29/2024 5:12:00 PM



12324
5/29/2024 4:53:00 PM
J0410


12328
5/29/2024 4:37:00 PM
J0410


11851
5/29/2024 3:54:00 PM
K1030


12354
5/29/2024 2:13:00 PM
K1340


12333
5/29/2024 1:51:00 PM
K1340


12342
5/29/2024 1:36:00 PM
J0340


20014
5/29/2024 1:16:00 PM
J0340


11822
5/29/2024 12:52:00 PM
J0340



